# Blogger Drop Down Menus Try 2

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

So after many hours of Google searches and many more editing and trying to understand CSS code for drop down menus in Blogger (Why doesn't Google just provide a widget for these anyway???),  I now have an example that is 98% of the way to what I want.  The HTML and CSS are attached.  I'd really to make 2 changes which I couldn't figure out.

1. I'd like the top level menu to be centered on the page.  Sounds easy but I didn't find it so
2. Under the PORTFOLIO menu, WILDLIFE/NATURE submenu, I'd like to shift the box of the the subsubmenu to be completely off of its parent menu, i.e. so no menu items in the PORTFOLIO menu are hidden.

I can live with this the way it is but if I can get these last 2 things done, I'd be golden.   Thanks.

```css
#cssnav {
     float: left;
     overflow: hidden;
}

#cssnav ul {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style:none;
}

#cssnav ul li {
 float:left;
}

#cssnav ul li a {
    float: left;
    font: 16px Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    color:black;
    padding: 10px 40px; /*1st number is top & bottom. 2nd is left & rght. */
   text-decoration:none;
}

#cssnav ul li a:hover,
#cssnav ul li:hover > a {
     color: black;   /* main menu hover color */
}

#cssnav li ul a:hover, 
#cssnav ul li li:hover > a  {
    color: black; /*submenu text color */
     text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

#cssnav li ul {
     left: -999em;
     margin: 35px 0 0;
     position: absolute;
     width: 340px; /* width of submenu box */
     z-index: 9999;
}

#cssnav li:hover ul {
     left: auto; /* where the left edge of the drop down box aligns */
}

/* Drop down box formatting */
#cssnav li ul a {
     margin-right: 0;
     width: 260px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
     border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#cssnav li li ul {
     margin: -1px 0 0 160px;
     visibility:hidden;
}

/* no idea what this does */
#cssnav li li:hover ul {
     visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="cssnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
<ul>
<li><a ref='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/Landscapes'>
LANDSCAPES</a></li>
<li><a href=' '>WILDLIFE/NATURE</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/WildlifeFlowers-1/Birds/'>
BIRDS</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/WildlifeFlowers-1/Butterflies/'>BUTTERFLIES</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/WildlifeFlowers-1/Flowers/'>FLOWERS</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/2017-Photo-of-the-Week/'>PHOTO OF THE WEEK</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/Landscapes-1/2017-Michigan-Calendar-Photos/'>2017 CALENDAR PHOTOS</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/Notecards'>
NOTECARDS</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Contact">CONTACT ME</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/About-Me2">ABOUT ME</a></li>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code to achieve what you're looking for. I put `width: 100%` on your main navigation `div`, and used `text-align: center` and `display: inline-block` to center the menu.

Formatting the subnavs was a little more complicated. I added `position: relative` to the `li` elements so we could position the sub navs around their parents. In order to get the third-level subnav off of its parent, I applied `left: 100%` to it to move it all the way to the side. I also removed the `margin` style on the sub nav under Wildlife.

I also added some `drop-shadow` and additional `:hover` styling to make the experience a little better for the user.

Hope this helps! More comments in the CSS.

```css
#cssnav {
     width: 100%; /* Spanned div across page */
     text-align: center; /* Centered <ul> inside */
}

#cssnav ul {
 display: inline-block; /* Allows text-align:center to affect Menu */
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style:none;
}

#cssnav ul li {
 float:left;
 text-align: left; /* Keeps menus left aligned */
 position: relative; /* Allows us to position sub menus relative to their parent */
}

#cssnav ul li a {
    float: left;
    font: 16px Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    color:black;
    padding: 10px 40px; /*1st number is top & bottom. 2nd is left & rght. */
   text-decoration:none;
}

#cssnav ul li a:hover,
#cssnav ul li:hover > a {
     color: black;   /* main menu hover color */
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

#cssnav li ul a:hover, 
#cssnav ul li li:hover > a  {
    color: black; /*submenu text color */
     text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

#cssnav li ul {
     left: 0;
     display: none;
     margin: 35px 0 0;
     position: absolute;
     width: 340px; /* width of submenu box */
     z-index: 9999;
     background: white;
     box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
     -webkit-padding-start:0px !important;
}

#cssnav li:hover ul {
     display: block;
}

/* Drop down box formatting */
#cssnav li ul a {
     margin-right: 0;
     width: 260px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
     border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#cssnav li li ul {
     visibility:hidden;
}

/* no idea what this does */
#cssnav li li:hover ul {
     visibility:visible;
     left: 100%; /* Puts sub nav next to parent, not over it */
}
```

```html
<div id="cssnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
<ul>
<li><a ref='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/Landscapes'>
LANDSCAPES</a></li>
<li><a href=' '>WILDLIFE/NATURE</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/WildlifeFlowers-1/Birds/'>
BIRDS</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/WildlifeFlowers-1/Butterflies/'>BUTTERFLIES</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/WildlifeFlowers-1/Flowers/'>FLOWERS</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/2017-Photo-of-the-Week/'>PHOTO OF THE WEEK</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/Landscapes-1/2017-Michigan-Calendar-Photos/'>2017 CALENDAR PHOTOS</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/Notecards'>
NOTECARDS</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Contact">CONTACT ME</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/About-Me2">ABOUT ME</a></li>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code run on the snippet looks great!  But on my Blogger page, the submenus fall behind the blog articles.  :(

Comment: By the way, the centering of the main menu works fine.  It's the formatting of the submenus where the problem lies.

Comment: Can you link to your live project? There must be conflicting styles or something in Google's embedded stylesheet.

Comment: Well the centering isn't working how I want it to either.  I really appreciate your effort.  But the centering code centers the menu items too and I don't want those centered. I want them staying left justified.  Funny thing is, it looks great when I run your snippet above but I've had this happen before. As soon as I take the code to Blogger, it doesn't work like that.  Not sure where the conflict is. I don't have any other mods in my Blogger account.

Comment: When you say "link to your live project", exactly what do you mean?  Post the URL for my blog?  I'm obviously no CSS/HTML wizard.  :)

Comment: @Kentinada Yes, if you could post the URL of where you're trying to implement this, it'd be helpful to see the full source code.

Comment: Sorry  @JesseRogers, I didn't see your comment a couple days ago.  My blog is blog.adahighlanderphotography.com.

Comment: No problem. Okay, if you add `overflow: visible;` to `#cssnav li ul` and change `#cssnav li li ul` to `margin: 0; left: 100% !important;`, it should all work beautifully on a desktop browser.

Comment: I think I did what you said but it still doesn't work for me.  Any chance you can take another look?

Comment: Are you having a problem now where you hover over "portfolio" and the menu doesn't show up?

Comment: @Kentinada Try adding `overflow: visible;` to `#cssnav ul`. Not sure why that suddenly started cutting off your sub-menus when it wasn't doing that before.

Comment: @Kentinada glad to hear it! If I've solved your problem, please hit the "accept answer" check mark.

Comment: I just hit the Accept check mark.  Not sure if this is the right place to ask or not but is there a way to put a ">" symbol out to the right of the Wildlife/Nature menu item so people know there is a submenu to it?

Comment: A follow on question to this thread:  The code all works great EXCEPT that it doesn't update the URL address bar when I click on a link.  It leaves it alone.  If I delete the URL, then click on a drop down link, it goes to the right page on my website but the URL bar stays blank.  Ideas?

Comment: I'd be happy to but it has been a while since I've posted here and can't remember how to add code blocks.   Where do I do that?
My blog is blog.adahighlanderphotography.com.

Comment: That'll work. I'll take a look when I get to the office!

Comment: What I'm seeing is that your whole site is being generated into a `<frame>` element, similar to an `iframe`. So when you click on links, it looks like it's running a bunch of scripts to reload to page inside that frame without doing an actual browser refresh and reloading the full DOM at a new URL. It also looks like some of the links in your nav have `<a href="#">` still set as the link, but when you hover on them, it shows the correct link. I'm gonna have to just assume SmugMug has a really... _unconventional_ dev process and recommend you look at other platforms that are more up to date.

Comment: I don't think the problem is on SmugMug's side.  When I start on their side, and pick any of my menu items, the URL updates fine.  It's when I am on the blogger side that my menu choices don't get reflected in the URL window.